# Symfony injecting cannot inject doctrine object

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using Symfony 2, and i m trying to create a custom service container that handle some calculations

my services.yml

```
services:
    my_calculator:
        class:        my_app\HomeBundle\Services\CalculatorService
        arguments:    [doctrine]
```

CalculatorService is as below

```
<?php 
namespace my_app\HomeBundle\Services;

use my_app\CategoryBundle\Entity;

class CalculatorService
{
    protected $doctrine;

    public function __construct($doctrine)
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }

    public function calculate($data=array())
    {
        if(!empty($data))
        {
        }
    }
}
```

my controller function

```
public function calculateAction()
{
    $request = $this->get('request');

    $calculator=$this->get('my_calculator');
 }
```

my problem that doctrine object dosen't get get to the constructor

i have tried to `arguments:    [@doctrine]`
and `arguments:    [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]`

but i get parsing error once i write `@` at the yml file

please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working code sample for entity manager injection.

services.yml

```
my_service:
    class: GLS\DemoBundle\MyService
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

Service class:

```
class MyService
{
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

}
```